# При запуске 2 методов main изменения переменных не фиксируются

Tags: java, многопоточность, main

Всем привет) Столкнулся с интересным для себя моментом: Понимаю что пример притянут за уши, но тем не менее

Допустим у меня есть класс Main, с одним полем и одним методом

> public class Main {

> ```
> public static boolean isLive = false;
>
> public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
>     while (true) {
>         isLive = true;
>
>         Thread.sleep(1000);
>
>         System.out.println(Cat.isLive);
>     }
> }
> ```

и класс Cat с одним полем и одним методом

> public class Cat {
>
> ```
> public static boolean isLive = false;
>
> public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
>     while (true) {
>         Thread.sleep(1000);
>
>         isLive = true;
>
>         System.out.println(Main.isLive);
>
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

При запуске двух методов main, я думал, что выводы переменных, рано или поздно (через 1 сек) , придут к true. Но был сильно удивлен, когда узнал, что изменения значения в переменных вообще не происходит. Точнее происходит, но другой метод main об этом не узнает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так получается, что метод main видит изменения переменных только в своем классе, но не видит изменений другого класса

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: а как запустить 2 метода мейн?
 и как значение переменной перезапишется, если бесконечный цикл?

Comment: @стасевич 2 метода маин запускается так же, как и один (мышкой нажимаете у второго класса на метод main и выбираете запустить).Конечный/бесконечный цикл не влияют на присвоение переменной нового значения

Comment: я имею ввиду, что запуская поочередно мейн это разные треды, их надо объединять в одном потоке...

Comment: и почитайте про ключевое слово volatile

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вы запускаете два разных процесса. У каждого процесса своя память, так что даже если они будут обращаться к одной и той же переменной, то у каждого процесса она будет своя.

Во-вторых, в этой программе каждый класс использует свою статическую переменную. Это значит, что даже если бы два метода main выполнялись в рамках одного процесса (это можно сделать используя многопоточность), то это все равно две разные переменные в памяти, и изменения одной никак бы не повлияли на другую.

Comment: С первой частью ответа соглашусь) спасибо), а вот ко второй вопросы: 2 и более потоков, могут смело переписывать одну переменную (опустим затирание  данных и т д)Т.е если у меня будет одна статическая переменная,то она будет общей для моих двух потоков , а вы говорите, что это две разные переменные в памяти

Comment: Потоки конечно же могут использовать одну и ту же переменную. Но в ваших классах `Cat` и `Main` определены две разные переменные с одним именем. Если бы в `Cat.main` вы обращались к переменной из класса `Main` так `Main.isLive = true`, то это была бы работа с одной переменной, а сейчас каждый класс работает со своей переменной.

Comment: Понял про что вы )спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Причина такая же, как и в ситуации, когда у двух людей на двух одинаковых телефонах есть фотоальбомы, но фотографии в них разные. Ведь кроме названий телефонов и приложения ничего общего тут больше нет. Так и у вас - одинаковые имена переменых не означает, что эта переменные вообще как-то связаны друг с другом.